# Learning How To Develop Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I really love the idea of having the freedom to extend the editor and I'm looking at learning how to develop an extension.

I'm very new to JavaScript (my experience is with C/C++) but it is the language I would prefer to use to develop an extension as I've not had any experience with TypeSript.

I have gone through the available documentation and have a general understanding of the files and code generated to get started on developing an extension

Where I am struggling is with the API reference (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api), I don't understand how to read it and I'm slightly embarrassed about asking for help as it seems like such a trivial thing.

I've been going through the different sections of the API reference to spark some ideas on how I can get started but looking at the function definitions for example: `findFiles(include: GlobPattern, exclude?: GlobPattern | null, maxResults?: number, token?: CancellationToken): Thenable<Uri[]>` I am confused at how to make sense of them.

Just after some friendly help on how I can decipher the API reference to get a better understanding on how to use it properly.

Comment: Consider taking an existing simple extension and a) learning how it works and b) tweaking it a little.

Answer (score 1):

Go step by step. Don't start with API directly. Go to link

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world

You can see, it is too simple to create hello world extension. Try to understand this example. Once you understood this check another little bit complex examples.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/samples

Try to execute every extension and understand which APIs are used and why.

If you need more example you can directly go to VS code marketplace and browse through extensions. Almost 90 % of extensions are open source and its code is available on GitHub. Check GitHub links on right-hand side (See screenshot with red circle)

[image]

Check the documentation of every API used in this sample examples and slowly you will start to understand APIs .

Next step would be to create your own extension or contribute to existing extension available on GitHub.

Hope this will help :)